# pg_ctl start gives FATAL: role does not exist

Tags: postgresql

On my system, `whoami` returns `Dan`. I run `initdb` with the `--username=PgUser` argument. Then as OS user `Dan` I run `pg_ctl start` on the newly-initialized cluster, and it gives this output:

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2013-06-13 00:54:33 UTC
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
FATAL:  role "Dan" does not exist
 done
server started
```

The server appears to have started up normally. I believe the error occurs because it wants me to run `pg_ctl` as the OS user named `PgUser`. What I want to know is:

- Is that belief correct?
- Is there a way to specify the user as `PgUser` without using `su`? I would prefer not to create a new OS user and would like to use a PostgreSQL user with a different username (I'm doing some code refactoring that makes this more convenient).
- Is the instance I started crippled in some way because I started it as OS user `Dan`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you run `pg_ctl start` with the `-w` (wait) option, because it will try a test connection with a user that does not exist (in your case).  But that's not really a problem (except for the confusing error message), because that proves that the server is up.

Comment: Hm-hm, what do you think, is it possible somehow to adjust the error message so that is shows the (non)-severity of the issue? :)

Comment: Anything is possible. ;-)  Send in a bug.

Comment: Probably even better would be to use the actual Specified initial user (PgUser)